# Unable to parse XML - Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, android-databinding, kapt

[image]

```
Caused by: 
org.gradle.workers.internal.DefaultWorkerExecutor$WorkExecutionException: A
failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.res.ParseLibraryResourcesTask$ParseResourcesRunnable
```

#### Other error codes

```
FAILURE: Build completed with 2 failures.
```

### 1: Task failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:parseDebugLocalResources'.

> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.res.ParseLibraryResourcesTask$ParseResourcesRunnable
> Failed to parse XML file '/home/shinto/Documents/PostMethodTrialChecking/HelpIntern/app/build/intermediates/packaged_res/debug/layout/fragment_signup.xml'

#### `fragment_signup.xml`

```
<data>
    <variable
        name="users"
        type="com.shinto.helpintern.MainViewModel" />
</data>
android:visibilities="@{users.}"
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    android:id="@+id/progBar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
```

Comment: Post the full errors.  This tells us nothing of what broke

Comment: sure @GabeSechan

Comment: I'm adding error message image.

Comment: From the logs, you have an 'a' character somewhere it doesn't make sense in fragment_signup.xml.

Comment: Can you post your `fragment_signup` XML?

Comment: Yea sure @LucaPizzini .Know i know where the issue is located.

Comment: Actually i got the solution Thank you very much @LucaPizzini. Thanks for sharing your valuable time.

Answer (score 1):

Your XML code is wrong. And as the error suggests, compiler expects a `<`, means an opening tag. Why?

Because this line
`android:visibilities="@{users.}"` is misplaced and isn't in any tag. Even if it was in its correct position, it wouldn't work, because there's nothing called `visibilities`, it's `visibility`.

I assume you want to toggle the visibility of the `ContraintLayout` based on any (assuming boolean) value of the data. To do that, change your code as:

```
<data>
    <import type="android.view.View"/>
    <variable
        name="users"
        type="com.shinto.helpintern.MainViewModel" />
</data>

<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    android:id="@+id/progBar"
    android:visibility="@{users.yourValue? View.GONE : View.VISIBLE}"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
```

This will toggle the layout's visibility based on the value of your model.

Comment: Thank you very much @LalitFauzdar. Your answer is very useful.